# Function of the various capacitors in the schematic below

Tags: transistors, capacitor

I'm trying to analyze the circuit below and I understand that the transistor T201 is acting like an inverter . Am I wrong ?
And also why are the two capacitors in parallel at the beginning of the circuit ?
I know that there are many parameters to be considered to select a capacitor such as working temp, temp coeff,working voltage ,leakage current etc., but how do they matter for the circuit below? 
what does "3A" at the input pin mean ? and also what does "10E"
 and "11G" at the output pins mean ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

T201 is a dual transistor, there is a PNP and an NPN part.  The T201(P) collector will float (so it will be pulled low by the T201(N) and T200 bases).  When VDD5 goes low, T201(P) will turn on and the bases of the other two will go high which will in turn pull their collectors low.  So I suppose you could say that T201 acts as an inverter, if that's what you meant.

The two caps in parallel are to provide better filtering of high frequency noise.  There are lots of other questions on here that go into a lot more detail of why this is done.  It's not a matter of temperature coefficients, working voltage, or leakage, it's about frequency response.

The labels you mentioned could be just references perhaps to other parts of the schematics.  10E and 11G don't mean much otherwise.  3A could indicate the expected current at that terminal, but perhaps not.  I expect there is not enough information provided to answer that.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean when you say the "collector will float"  ? and can you pls tell me what is the function of T200 ?

Comment: When the PNP part of T201 is off, it's collector will be allowed float to whatever voltage based on how the other connected devices influence it.  In this case, the PNP transistors have pull-down resistors at the bases, so that collector will be pulled-low.  The purpose of T200 is to pull down the voltage at P205, but beyond that I can't say what that does given only the portion of the schematic you provided.

Comment: what parameters should I consider when choosing a capacitor ? And the diodes in series is for protection against what ?Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: The capacitor factors you mentioned in your question are all relevant when selecting a cap, but in terms of why there are two and how it applies to this circuit, mainly it's voltage and value.  The voltage of course needs to exceed the max expected voltage seen on the P200 signal.  The value depends on what frequency cut-off they are expected to filter out.  The diodes are there to prevent the voltage exceeding the P204 and GND levels by more than ~0.7V

Comment: Thank you very much.And can I ask you one more thing, what formula  should be used here to calculate the capacitance ? Please help.

Comment: It's hard to answer that.  It depends on the purpose of the cap.  In this case they appear to be for filtering, but it's not clear if there is power or signal coming in from the TM+ point, or from VDD5.  If for example the power is coming from VDD5 only, then you have essentially an RC filter, and there are many examples of how to calculate the response, such as [this site](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRtool.php).  If it's just for bulk capacitance, there other factors involved such as ripple, ESR, load current, etc.

Comment: suppose  the TM+ point is a 12V input.

Comment: What is VDD5?  If you have extra information about the circuit, please provide whatever you know in the question.

Comment: the circuit is a temperature measurement circuit but I'm having trouble understanding how it works as a temperature measuring ckt. the outputs 10E and 11G go to a microcontroller. the microcontroller measures the voltage . i don't know how the temperature can be known from this. And the VDD5 is a 5V power supply i think.

Comment: akshatha.ve@gmail.com - my email. Can I get your email pls ?

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the minimum voltage at TM+ to turn on T201(NPN) and T200 ?

Comment: I think this should be moved to chat, but I don't know how to do that.  I assume P204 is not powered and is just a test point based on the symbol, so the voltage on TM+ would lose 0.7V passing through D200, then another 0.2V passing through T201 (PNP).  Then on each of the NPN devices, there is a pull-down and base resistor which are equal.  So the voltage would need to be about 1.4V to make the base at 0.7V assuming no base current.  0.7 + 0.2 + 1.4 = 2.3V.

Comment: You should probably see those transistors turn on at around that level or a little higher, like 2.5V because those built-in resistors are fairly large 10k and 22k.  This assumes VDD5 is not connected or grounded.

Comment: VDD5 is fixed 5V voltage . the TM+ voltage varies. How does the VDD5 affect the circuit ?

Comment: How would it lose 0.2 v when through T201(PNP) ?

Comment: what would happen if the diodes weren't present in the circuit ?

Comment: If TM+ varies (which is not what you stated previously), and VDD5 is fixed at 5V, then the PNP transistor will start turning on as TM+ rises above ~1.3V higher than 5V (0.7V in the diode and another 0.6V above the base voltage). The voltage drop from collector to emitter of a BJT is typically about 0.2V when turned on.  It seems you know little about electronics and are trying to understand too many different concepts at once.  I suggest you do some research online and then if still uncertain, ask new questions that are detailed, specific, and focused on individual topics.

Comment: It's not 0.2v here , depends on the transistor. Vce(sat) is 150mV here.

Comment: Hey can you please help me ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When does the transistor T201(PNP) fully turn on (at what voltage of TM+) and what will be its collector current and if the transistor T201(PNP) is fully turned on, Is it sufficient for the other two transistors to turn on ?

Comment: so the transistor t201(pnp) will turn on at about 5v+1.3(approx) and then there will a voltage drop of about 0.2v between C-e junction and now will the transistors T201(npn) and T200 turn on too ? what are the conditions for them to go into saturation ?

Comment: help please , or atleast suggest me some proper site or book to get my basics right

Comment: My suggestion is that if you are still learning this, don't start by trying to analyze this circuit.  You can get a lot of information online by searching.  For example www.allaboutcircuits.com is a good place to start.

Comment: But I have to analyse this circuit, it's my homework, kind of important.